# how to set global environment variable for Play 2.0 Framework?

Tags: jakarta-ee, playframework, environment-variables

on Windows 7 OS, I am trying to setup Play 2.0 Framework.

how do I set global environment variable for Play 2.0 ?

Comment: You can set it in "Configuration panel" > "System" > "Advanced" > "Env variables".

Comment: I know the place where it needs to be set, but what should be the 'Variable Name' and 'Variable Value' ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think Play 2.0 impose a variable name.
I suggest the classic convention "PLAY2_HOME", pointing to your play installation directory. In order to use Play from any console location, you also have to update your PATH variable (adding %PLAY2_HOME%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Play 2.0 impose a variable name. I suggest the classic convention "PLAY2_HOME", pointing to your play installation directory. In order to use Play from any console location, you also have to update your PATH variable (adding %PLAY2_HOME%)